# Makefile to compile multiple C programs?

Tags: c, makefile

This is an incredibly simple question, but I'm new to makefiles. I am trying to make a makefile that will compile two independent programs:

```
program1:
    gcc -o prog1 program1.c

program2:
    gcc -o prog2 program2.c
```

All the examples online go into way more details than I need and are confusing! All I really want it to do is to run the two `gcc` lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answers bellow are very clear, but you can also just run the command line: `make program1 program2` that will invoke both targets in the very example you gave yourself. If you just want `program1`, you can run just `make` (it will run the first target). If you just want `program2`, run `make program2`. You have more control. And of course, a target `all: program1 program2` will do just that (being it the first, running your 2 other targets). Done.

Comment: 12 years and still not a fulfilling answer? I'm also new to `make` and learned a lot from the answers below.

Answer (score 101):

Do it like so

```
all: program1 program2

program1: program1.c
    gcc -o program1 program1.c

program2: program2.c
    gcc -o program2 program2.c
```

You said you don't want advanced stuff, but you could also shorten it like this based on some default rules.

```
all: program1 program2

program1: program1.c
program2: program2.c
```

Comment: Note that if you want both programs to be built automatically, the `all` target must appear before the individual programs in the makefile, and be the first target in the makefile.

Comment: You can put `all` or any other target wherever you want and make it the default for target-less (what you called "automatic") runs of `make` using `.DEFAULT_GOAL:=all`.

Comment: What if there is a file with the name 'all'?

Answer (score 41):

[Pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) let you compile multiple c files which require the same compilation commands using `make` as follows:

```
objects = program1 program2
all: $(objects)

$(objects): %: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Instead of program1 and program2, what if you have thousands of ".c" files in various directories, sub-directories. How can we automate the same using above logic?

Comment: @SH' Use Make `shell` command to populate `objects` using the output of `find`. E.g., `objects := $(shell find . -type f -iname "*.c" -print | tr -d ".c" | sed 's/\///') `

Comment: @hmofrad answer with 'tr' will remove all matching characters ['.', 'c'], not a substring. Fix: `find tests/ -type f -iname '*.cpp' | sed 's/.cpp//g'`

Comment: I'm using this for learning c++. To quickly compile and test little scripts. What other use cases may be that require this config?

Answer (score 28):

```makefile
############################################################################
# 'A Generic Makefile for Building Multiple main() Targets in $PWD'
# Author:  Robert A. Nader (2012)
# Email: naderra at some g
# Web: xiberix
############################################################################
#  The purpose of this makefile is to compile to executable all C source
#  files in CWD, where each .c file has a main() function, and each object
#  links with a common LDFLAG.
#
#  This makefile should suffice for simple projects that require building
#  similar executable targets.  For example, if your CWD build requires
#  exclusively this pattern:
#
#  cc -c $(CFLAGS) main_01.c
#  cc main_01.o $(LDFLAGS) -o main_01
#
#  cc -c $(CFLAGS) main_2..c
#  cc main_02.o $(LDFLAGS) -o main_02
#
#  etc, ... a common case when compiling the programs of some chapter,
#  then you may be interested in using this makefile.
#
#  What YOU do:
#
#  Set PRG_SUFFIX_FLAG below to either 0 or 1 to enable or disable
#  the generation of a .exe suffix on executables
#
#  Set CFLAGS and LDFLAGS according to your needs.
#
#  What this makefile does automagically:
#
#  Sets SRC to a list of *.c files in PWD using wildcard.
#  Sets PRGS BINS and OBJS using pattern substitution.
#  Compiles each individual .c to .o object file.
#  Links each individual .o to its corresponding executable.
#
###########################################################################
#
PRG_SUFFIX_FLAG := 0
#
LDFLAGS := 
CFLAGS_INC := 
CFLAGS := -g -Wall $(CFLAGS_INC)
#
## ==================- NOTHING TO CHANGE BELOW THIS LINE ===================
##
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
PRGS := $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))
PRG_SUFFIX=.exe
BINS := $(patsubst %,%$(PRG_SUFFIX),$(PRGS))
## OBJS are automagically compiled by make.
OBJS := $(patsubst %,%.o,$(PRGS))
##
all : $(BINS)
##
## For clarity sake we make use of:
.SECONDEXPANSION:
OBJ = $(patsubst %$(PRG_SUFFIX),%.o,$@)
ifeq ($(PRG_SUFFIX_FLAG),0)
        BIN = $(patsubst %$(PRG_SUFFIX),%,$@)
else
        BIN = $@
endif
## Compile the executables
%$(PRG_SUFFIX) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJ)  $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BIN)
##
## $(OBJS) should be automagically removed right after linking.
##
veryclean:
ifeq ($(PRG_SUFFIX_FLAG),0)
    $(RM) $(PRGS)
else
    $(RM) $(BINS)
endif
##
rebuild: veryclean all
##
## eof Generic_Multi_Main_PWD.makefile
```

Comment: Thanks for the above code. I use it to compile my .c files. But if i change any of my myHeader.h files, then i need to re-save an the .c file before using 'make' or else it shows "make: Nothing to be done for `all'." whereas actually changes have been made in the .h file. Can we modify the make file to compile after any changes in .h files without re-saving the .c file? and thanks for the above code!!!

Comment: "$(OBJS) should be automagically removed right after linking." Doesn't that lead to unnecessary recompilation and, thus, mostly defeat the point of `make`?

Comment: Why do you nee `.SECONDEXPANSION`?

Comment: In Linux, macOS there is no need to `PRG_SUFFIX`. If you don't want suffix, set `PRG_SUFFIX=""`. Else if you set `PRG_SUFFIX=` or remove that line like `#PRG_SUFFIX=.exe`, you will get the `error: no such file or directory: 'all.o'` error.

Answer (score 10):

```
all: program1 program2

program1:
    gcc -Wall -o prog1 program1.c

program2:
    gcc -Wall -o prog2 program2.c
```

Answer (score 3):

```
all: program1 program2

program1:
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o prog1 program1.c

program2:
    gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o prog2 program2.c
```

I rather the ansi and pedantic, a better control for your program. It wont let you compile while you still have warnings !!

Comment: That is not what `-pedantic` is for. `-pedantic` will remove any non-ansi features that even `-ansi` permits.

Comment: To add to cnicutar's comment, `-Werror` will change warnings to errors.

Answer (score 1):

A simple program's compilation workflow is simple, I can draw it as a small graph: source -> [compilation] -> object [linking] -> executable. There are *files* (source, object, executable) in this graph, and *rules* (*make*'s terminology). That graph is definied in the *Makefile*.

When you launch make, it reads *Makefile*, and checks for changed *files*. If there's any, it triggers the *rule*, which depends on it. The *rule* may produce/update further *files*, which may trigger other *rules* and so on. If you create a good makefile, only the necessary *rules* (compiler/link commands) will run, which stands "to next" from the modified file in the dependency path.

Pick an example *Makefile*, read the manual for syntax (anyway, it's clear for first sight, w/o manual), and **draw the graph**. You have to understand compiler options in order to find out the names of the result files.

The make graph should be as complex just as you want. You can even do infinite loops (don't do)! You can tell *make*, which rule is your *target*, so only the left-standing *files* will be used as triggers.

Again: **draw the graph**!.

Answer (score 1):

```
SRC = a.cpp b.cpp
BIN = $(patsubst %.cpp,%,$(SRC))

all: $(BIN)

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN)

.PHONY: all clean
```

`make all` will do:

```
c++     a.cpp   -o a
c++     b.cpp   -o b
```

If you set `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` variables `make` will use them.

Comment: Did you mean `a.cpp -o a`?

Answer (score 1):

This will compile all `*.c` files upon `make` to executables without the `.c` extension as in `gcc program.c -o program`.

`make` will automatically add any flags you add to `CFLAGS` like `CFLAGS = -g Wall`.

If you don't need any flags `CFLAGS` can be left blank (as below) or omitted completely.

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
EXECS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%)
CFLAGS = 

all: $(EXECS)
```