# How to make `make` make an a executable for each C file in a folder?

Tags: c, makefile

My question is deceptively simple, but I have lost several hours of study trying to get the solution. I'm trying to create a Makefile that builds an executable for each .c file in a directory.

I have tried the following:

```
CC = gcc
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))

all: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPFLAGS)  -c  $<
```

but this way it is creating only `.o` files, and not any executables. I need a rule that makes an executable for each of these `.o` files. Something like the following:

```
gcc src.o -o src
```

Comment: FWIW,

HTH

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950395/makefile-to-compile-multiple-c-programs/13696012#13696012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9995393/318716) answer doesn't seem to work on my machine.  Perhaps, as the complete Makefile:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)

all: $(SRCS:.c=)

.c:
     gcc $(CPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

(The last two lines, are on my machine, unnecessary, as the default rules are adequate.)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Very Thank.
was not able to properly use ':.'

Comment: @eduardomoroni: You should note that the name of your macro `CPFLAGS` is non-standard. It should typically be `CFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` or both. See [CFLAGS vs CPPFLAGS](//stackoverflow.com/q/2754966).

Comment: Nice answer. What about adding a `clean` target ?

Comment: For at least GNU `make` the `.c` rule is entirely unnecessary (and isn't worth its own declaration) -- GNU `make` knows how to build from C files without explicit rules. Otherwise all good :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `all` is telling it just to build the object files.  Add something like

EXEC = $(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRCS))

all: $(EXEC)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
% : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
all: $(basename $(wildcard *.c))
```

and you don't even need the first two lines, as `make` knows how to compile and link .c files into executables. Still, it is often necessary to change `make`'s built-in recipes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Makefile I use to compile a bunch of scheme files.

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.scm)

all: $(SRCS:.scm=)

%: %.scm
    chicken-csc -o $@ $<
```