# Makefile in C with multiple sources

Tags: c, makefile

I am currently learning C and now I am upto the tutorial where I need to write the Makefile but I am difficulty writing a Makefile for multiple sources. Can someone tell me how I can correct my code for the Makefile for multiple sources? All of the files are in the same directory and there are a total of 3 C source files as indicated by filename1/2/3 etc. I am trying to build 3 separate programs with 3 source files in a single makefile

```
 OPT = -O4              

all: filename1

filename1: filename1.o 
    gcc $(OPT) -o filename1 filename1.o

filename1.o: filename1.c
    gcc $(OPT) -c filename1.c

filename2: filename2.o 
    gcc $(OPT) -o filename2 filename2.o

filename2.o: filename2.c
    gcc $(OPT) -c filename2.c   

filename3: filename3.o 
    gcc $(OPT) -o filename3 filename3.o

filename3.o: filename3.c
    gcc $(OPT) -c filename3.c       
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f filename1
    rm -f filename2
    rm -f filename3
```

Or is my code fine for what I want it to do?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this Makefile per se.  What is it that you want it to do that it is not doing?

Comment: Are you trying to build three separate programs or one program that uses three source files?

Comment: I am trying to build 3 separate programs with 3 source files in a single makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so there doesn't appear to be anything **wrong** with the makefile, given that you're making three different programs.  It should work.

Some suggestions for making it a little more usable:

1) Declare the "all" and "clean" targets to be phony.  This will prevent Make from trying to make files called "all" and "clean".

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

2) You probably want your "all" target to build all three of your programs, not just one, so change that to:

```
all: filename1 filename2 filename3
```

3) If you end up using this to make more than three programs, and they all share similar build procedures, you can collapse your rules into a smaller set using pattern matches.  See Martin Beckett's answer for an example.  But, that's not necessary.

Comment: Whoops, looks like Martin Beckett maybe deleted his answer.  Anyhow, you probably don't need to worry about making your Makefile elegant and pretty just yet.  Separate handwritten rules work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Your makefile should work, but it could be simplified.

The `make` utility supports implicit rules. This can simplify common operations, such as compiling a C source code file into an object file and compiling an object file into an executable.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-O4

all: filename1 filename2 filename3

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $* $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f filename1
    rm -f filename2
    rm -f filename3
```

Answer (score 2):

For three separate programs built from three files like that, you could simply use:

```
PROGRAMS = filename1 filename2 filename3

all: ${PROGRAMS}

clean:
    rm -f ${PROGRAMS} ${PROGRAMS:=.o}
```

You might add:

```
CFLAGS = -O4
```

to get that level of optimization.  You might use a macro instead of the `rm` command; generally, mature `makefile`s use a lot of macros:

```
RM_F = rm -f
```

If you're targeting GNU Make, you could add:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

And the list goes on.

The key point is that `make` knows how to build single-file programs already, and it knows how to compile C source into an object file, so you don't have to train it to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching:

```
PROGS = filename1 filename2 filename3

all: $(PROGS)

# cancel implicit program rule
%: %.c

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(OPT) $(CFLAGS) $^ -c -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW,

HTH

'A Generic Makefile for Building Multiple main() Targets in $PWD'

[Makefile to compile multiple c programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950395/makefile-to-compile-multiple-c-programs/13696012#13696012)