# MinGW GCC wildcard to compile all files (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, operating-system, mingw

I'm using MinGW GCC compiler on windows,
I need to compile all c files in a folder!

I've tried

```
gcc  *.c -o  Output {folder Path}
```

I got this error

```
gcc: error: *.c: Invalid argument 
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

then the compilation terminated.

the used version of GCC is 4.7.1

Comment: You need to use a POSIX shell to do this. POSIX programs expect wildcards be expanded by the shell.

Answer (score 6):

gcc does not accept a wildcard (*.c) as input file.

You may write a script (batch@windows or .sh @Linux/Unix) which finds all source files and compile them one by one.

but you SHOULD use a makefile or CMAKE to organize your sources and their buildsystem. please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950395/makefile-to-compile-multiple-c-programs)

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing basically the same thing (i.e. use MinGW GCC on Windows with C files). I use the **-g** option for each directory whose *.c/.h* files I want included in the compilation.

For example, if I want to compile everything in the *myFolder* directory, this works for me:

```
gcc -g c:\myFolder\*.c -o foo.exe
```

Note you can use the **-g** option multiple times on the commandline to include multiple directories. For example, I organize my `.c/.h` files into various subfolders inside *myFolder*. So to tell **gcc** about *mySubdir* that is inside *myFolder*, this is what I do:

```
gcc -g c:\myFolder\*.c -g c:\myFolder\mySubdir\*.c -o foo.exe
```

Note that for any *.h* files that I put in such sub directories that I need to reference from C files in the parent dir, I have to use the relative path in `#include`.

For example, to reference *foo.h*, which lives inside *myFolder/subDir*, from a C file that lives in *myFolder*, I do:

```
#include "mySubdir/foo.h"
```

And that's basically it.

Now, for the sake of completeness, if you happen to use VSCode as I am for my C work (which is not necessarily optimal, but ok'ish), then you can tweak this setting in the *.vscode/tasks.json*, specifying each `-g` option separately, for example:

```json
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/*.c",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}/mySubdir/*.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
```

(my GCC version is 10.3.0)