# How do I specify which of two kernel modules to compile with a Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel-module

I have a Makefile that compiles two Linux kernel modules (`mod1.c` and `mod2.c`).

```
obj-m = mod1.o mod2.o
KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/
PWD=$(shell pwd)

# build the modules
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

#cleanup
clean:
    rm -rf *.ko *.o *.mod* .*.cmd modules.order Module.symvers .tmp_versions
```

This works fine to build both kernel modules when I run `make`, but I would like to be able to specify which module to build. For example, `make mod1` to compile `mod1.c` and `make mod2` to compile `mod2.c`.

The thing that I am unsure of is how to handle `obj-m`. Otherwise, specifying which program to compile [is well described online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950395/makefile-to-compile-multiple-c-programs).

Comment: My make foo is a bit rusty, but I don't see where you ever reference/consume `obj-m`, so just delete the line entirely?  You still need to add the two additional targets.

Comment: Hi @jwdonahue thank you for the reply. That line is necessary (as far as I understand) as it tells the system to build `mod1.o` from `mod1.c`, and after linking, this will become `mod1.ko` (the same is true of `mod2.c`). Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

Comment: Then shouldn't it be `:=`?  Or is the space around the equals symbol that makes it special in this variant of make?  Like I said, I am rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel uses variables to set kernel modules on/off:

```
CROSS_COMPILE ?= /path/to/compiler/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
T1      ?= n
T2      ?= n

obj-$(T1) += test1.o
obj-$(T2) += test2.o
LINUX_SOURCE_DIR=/path/to/linux


all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_SOURCE_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules ARCH=arm

test1:
        $(MAKE) T1=m

test2:
        $(MAKE) T2=m

clean:
        rm *o modules.order Module.symvers *mod.c
```

You can use this as `make T1=m` or `make test2`.

Comment: I've played a lot with this some years ago and as far as I remember this is kind of your only option because it's parsed by "KConfig" before it's passed to "Make". Would love to see some attempts tho!

Comment: This is neat. The `make T1=m` works for me, but `make test2` didn't seem to work. I get an error: `cc     mod1.c   -o mod1
mod1.c:1:24: fatal error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: I've tested this by calling `make test1` in the same directory. Did you use `make -C /path/ test1` or something else?

Comment: `CROSS_COMPILE` is not needed. One may specify it via command line. `LINUX_HEADERS` is a misleading name, it should be build folder.